# Angular NPM - No matching version found for mime@1.6.0

Tags: angular, npm, npm-update

My .npmrc file looks like:

```js
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<yourOrganization>/_packaging/<yourFeed>/npm/registry/

always-auth=true
```

I removed node_modules and tried to install the packages, I am getting following error

```js
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for mime@1.6.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'send'
npm ERR! notarget
```

My package.json does not contain any dependencies named `mime@1.6.0`.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `package-lock.json` file and install again?

Comment: Check `npm ls --all` to see it. `send` depends on `mime`, which (apparently) isn't stored in your `pkgs.dev.azure.com` registry. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops

Comment: @msbit I followed the link you shared and I could see that upstream is configured to https://registry.npmjs.org and its updated today.

Comment: @HoangTranSon yea tried. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the mime@1.6.0 package was permanently deleted in the feed. So we created a different feed and that feed was child from NPM repository so that created feed was having mime@1.6.0